How to remove duplicate and put in clipboard without affecting the Source range selected in excel MS365
I wanted to cover 2 questions

I would like to create a macro in personal.xlsb which can remove duplicate of the selected range and put in Clipboard without removing the duplicate from the source range selected. Only the clipboard values should have the duplicates removed. I created a transpose of the selected range with commas for each of them but when I execute I see that the source I selected is removed the duplicate and it affects my source. But I only want the results in the clipboard to have the duplicates removed. Below is the code
Sub cpbd()

 With GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
      Selection.Rows.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
      ''Range(Selection.Rows(1), Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
     .SetText Join(Evaluate("transpose(" & Selection.Address & ")"), ",")
     .PutInClipboard
    End With
End Sub

Also I find that this vba is not always working for some reason and I dont know if its the problem with the code GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

I would like a shortcut Ctrl + E to use for this in Excel but I see that Ctrl + E is already used as a shortcut for flash fill. I do not use flash fill shortcut. I would like to assign Ctrl + E for the above script.


If there is a better and robust VB script which you can provide I really appreciate it.

Try this code:
Sub cpbd()

 With GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
      TempRow = Selection.Rows
      Selection.Rows.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
      .SetText Join(Evaluate("transpose(" & Selection.Address & ")"), ",")
     .PutInClipboard
      Selection.Rows = TempRow
    End With
End Sub

This link will have the answer to the second part of your question:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/run-macro-excel-create-macro-button/#:~:text=On%20the%20Developer%20tab%2C%20in,interest%2C%20and%20then%20click%20Run.

This wonderful..Thanks for your response for the script. I see 2 issues 1 ) I get result like this  abc,bad,dad,5dd,,,,,,,,,, that is an extra commas for the duplicates existed in the range 2) I am seeing the format of the range changing in the source file  ie if there are some cells highlighted in yellow for some significance in the source report I see its changing to No color. Guess it changing to format of the report and cannot save after I check this script. This stop me from doing further analysis of the report as the format of the report changed.

Kindly suggest why my code creates an extra commas in result when pasted from clipboard. the result looks like this aaa,abc,add,,,,,,,,,,,

Use this to get rid of extra commas:
.SetText Join(Evaluate("transpose(filter(" & Selection.Address & "," & Selection.Address & "<>""""))"), ",")

Thanks Majed .that works it removes extra commas however the only issue with the whole script provided is it changes the text format of last rows selected to general format from text format .So when I have a text "477000081531" after running the script it changes to 4.77E+11. This is affecting any reports I check this script.Any suggestions??
